# SI unit for the speed of light through a vacuum

Tags: speed-of-light, speed, dimensional-analysis, si-units

What is the SI unit for the speed of light through a vacuum? For example for mass it is kilograms and for force it is $\rm kg\, m\, s^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions of any speed are length/time, so one choice of units could be meters/second.